# You cannot define a correlation name 'tdv' more than once [] [] , magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3

I have create custom admin FORM and use 2 product attributes as field select option
but in getting error.

```
"You cannot define a correlation name 'tdv' more than once"
```

If i have use single attribute in Form then it's working fine. 
Any idea how can it resolve ?

Here is my code:

```
static public function getOptionArray3()
        {
            $data_array=array();

            $attributeCode = 'size';
            $entityType = 'catalog_product';

            $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $attributeInfo = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                                           ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);



            $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

            $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                               
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();  

            foreach ($attributeOptionAll as $attributeOption) {
                $data_array[$attributeOption->getOptionId()] = $attributeOption->getValue();
            }                                                    

            return($data_array);
        }

        static public function getOptionArray6()
        {
            $data_array=array();

            $attributeCode = 'use_the_mattress';
            $entityType = 'catalog_product';

            $objectManager1 =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $attributeInfo = $objectManager1->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                                           ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);

            $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

            $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager1->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                               
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();  

            foreach ($attributeOptionAll as $attributeOption) {
                $data_array[$attributeOption->getOptionId()] = $attributeOption->getValue();
            }                                                    

            return($data_array);
        }
```

Comment: can you post your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code. It should work. You've used get method in getting collection. That's why it was working for first object only.

**$_objectManager->create()** creates new instance of the object, no-matter-what

**$_objectManager->get()** first tries to find shared instance (already created), if it's not found - it just creates new shared instance

```
static public function getOptionArray3()
{
    $data_array=array();

    $attributeCode = 'size';
    $entityType = 'catalog_product';

    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $attributeInfo = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                                   ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);



    $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

    $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                            ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                            ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                               
                            ->setStoreFilter()
                            ->load();  

    foreach ($attributeOptionAll as $attributeOption) {
        $data_array[$attributeOption->getOptionId()] = $attributeOption->getValue();
    }                                                    

    return($data_array);
}

static public function getOptionArray6()
{
    $data_array=array();

    $attributeCode = 'use_the_mattress';
    $entityType = 'catalog_product';

    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $attributeInfo = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                                   ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);

    $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

    $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                            ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                            ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)                                               
                            ->setStoreFilter()
                            ->load();  

    foreach ($attributeOptionAll as $attributeOption) {
        $data_array[$attributeOption->getOptionId()] = $attributeOption->getValue();
    }                                                    

    return($data_array);
}
```

**Note:** I will not recommend you to use Object Manager, instead use proper method to call function and avoid duplication of code.

Comment: Thanks , Abhishek Panchal really you save me time :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather to use Objectmanager try below code its worked for me:

```
public function __construct(
    ............,
    ............,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attributeOptionCollection
) {
    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    $this->_attributeOptionCollection = $attributeOptionCollection;
}

public function execute()
{
    $optionFactory = $this->optionFactory->create();
    $optionFactory->load('5529'); // load by option value
    $attributeId = $optionFactory->getAttributeId(); // atribute id of given option value
    $attributeOptionCollectionFac = $this->_attributeOptionCollection->create();
    $optionData = $attributeOptionCollectionFac
                        ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                        ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                        ->setIdFilter('5529')
                        ->setStoreFilter()
                        ->load();
}
```